# how to cut the left side of a "U" arrow in chemfig?

Tags: arrows, chemfig

I would like to reduce the left side of the  "U" arrow in chemfig.

```
\arrow{-U>[][\chemfig{ROH}][][.25]}[0,2]
```

[image]

Using the "shorten" command results in deformation.

```
\arrow{-U>[][\chemfig{ROH}][][.25]}[0,2,shorten <=20pt]
```

[image]

Any suggestion?

Comment: From the sketch you added to your question, it seems as if you wanted to shorten the overall width of the arrow. Would you alternatively also be interested in keeping the length of the horizontal arrow while moving the curved arrow more to the left? This would result in a more consistent output, especially if you also use other types of arrows in your document. Here is an example output of such a modified arrow in comparison to the original:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeBCv.png

Comment: @leandriis ----   can be done this way, yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I copied the definition of the `-lU>` type arrow, renamed it to `-lU>` and altered the line marked with `<--------`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\catcode`\_=11
\definearrow5{-lU>}{%
    \CF_arrowshiftnodes{#3}%
    \CF_expafter{\draw[}\CF_arrowcurrentstyle](\CF_arrowstartnode)--(\CF_arrowendnode)node[near start](Uarrow@arctangent){};% <-------- replaced [midway] with [near start]. Alternatively, use [pos=0.25] or any other value of your choice to fine tune the arrow position.
    \CF_ifempty{#4}
        {\def\CF_Uarrowradius{0.333}}
        {\def\CF_Uarrowradius{#4}}%
    \CF_ifempty{#5}%
        {\def\CF_Uarrowabsangle{60}}
        {\pgfmathsetmacro\CF_Uarrowabsangle{abs(#5)}}% ne prendre en compte que la valeur absolue de l'angle
    \expandafter\draw\expanded{[\CF_ifempty{#1}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}},-]}(Uarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Uarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=-\CF_Uarrowabsangle]node(Uarrow@start){};
    \expandafter\draw\expanded{[\CF_ifempty{#2}{draw=none}{\unexpanded\expandafter{\CF_arrowcurrentstyle}}]}(Uarrow@arctangent)%
        arc[radius=\CF_compoundsep*\CF_currentarrowlength*\CF_Uarrowradius,start angle=\CF_arrowcurrentangle-90,delta angle=\CF_Uarrowabsangle]node(Uarrow@end){};
    \pgfmathsetmacro\CF_temp{\CF_Uarrowradius*cos(\CF_arrowcurrentangle)<0?"-":"+"}%
    \ifdim\CF_Uarrowradius pt>0pt
        \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#1}{0}\CF_temp{Uarrow@start}{#2}{1}\CF_temp{Uarrow@end}%
    \else
        \CF_arrowdisplaylabel{#2}{0}\CF_temp{Uarrow@start}{#1}{1}\CF_temp{Uarrow@end}%
    \fi
}
\catcode`\_=8


\begin{document}
\schemestart
A
\arrow{-U>[][\chemfig{ROH}][][.25]}[0,2]
original
\schemestop

\schemestart
A
\arrow{-lU>[][\chemfig{ROH}][][.25]}[0,2]
modified
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

Comment: Work very well, thanks.

Comment: there is a problem.
when I use the new command \arrow{-lU>, chemfig has problems with superscripts and subscripts, \chemfig{H_2} results in "H_2".

Comment: @EdsonMarcon: Sorry, I forgot to add a line which caused this unexpected behavior. I just updated my answer with the corrected code.

Comment: worked well.
thanks again